# Can't pipe mediastream object nor Mediarecorder blob to google speech to text streaming interface

Tags: node.js, google-speech-api, mediastream

I am trying to implement real time transcription in which the browser receives the audio input and sends it a server, which then sends it to the google API interface for transcription.

I  looked into two APIs for browser audio input, Mediastream API and MediaRecorder API. Moreover I am using the google speech to text streaming request api to implement this. I have tried two ways:

1. I used getusermedia to obtain my Mediastream object. I piped it to the server using a websocket. But, I can't seem to pipe it to the the google's speech to text api.
2. I then used mediarecorder on top of getusermedia and sent 1 second blobs to the server using a websocket. However, the blobs can't be piped to the google's speech to text api.

So, my question is how do I take audio input from the browser, send it to my server and then to the googles speech to text api interface?